# Inequality between $\ln$ and $-x$.

Tags: calculus

I should prove that $\ln (1-x)<-x$ if $0<x<1$. I use that the function $g(x)=x+\ln(1-x)$ has a derivative $g'(x)=-\displaystyle\frac{x}{1-x}$ which is negative between $0<x<1$ then $g(x)$ is non-increasing in this interval. Can I conclude from $g(0)=0$ that $g(x)<0$ on $0<x<1$. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Mean value theorem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem, for any $x\in(0,1)$, we have $g(x)=g(0)+(x-0)g'(c)$ for some $c\in(0,x)$. But with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(c)<0$, we have $g(x)=xg'(c)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, note that $\log (1-x)$ is concave and $y=-x$ is the tangent at $x=0$.